# How to get the real file from S3 using CarrierWave

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have an application that reads the content of a file and indexes it. I was storing them in the disk itself, but now I'm using Amazon S3, so the following method doesn't work anymore.

It was something like this:

```
def perform(docId)
    @document = Document.find(docId)
    if @document.file?

      #You should't create a new version
      @document.versionless do |doc|
        @document.file_content = Cloudoc::Extractor.new.extract(@document.file.file)
        @document.save
      end

    end
  end
```

`@document.file` returns the `FileUploader`, and `doc.file.file` returns the `CarrierWave::Storage::Fog::File` class.

How can I get the real file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Calling `@document.file.read` will get you the contents of the file from S3 in Carrierwave.

Comment: Jacob, from carrierwave google group solved with `open(@document.file.url)` too

Comment: @document.file.read is probably better because it will work regardless of file storage used, i.e. it works with both local filesystem and S3.

Comment: the .read didn't work for us (we are using cloudinary in combination with carrierwave)

Comment: HI @Zachary, I am getting  **The specified key does not exist** if i use **@document.file.read** , could you please help me with this.