# How to access file hash of carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3

I have a music platform in development, and I upload tracks using carrierwave and fog to an S3 bucket.

I want to get access to the temporary file before it gets uploaded. I noticed when I send the file to the controller I get the following when I do `@track.file.inspect` in the console:

```
#<AudioUploader:0x007fa46d07bb60 @model=#<Track id: nil, artist_id: 1, title: "Not Alone", file: nil, created_at:
nil, updated_at: nil, track_cover: nil, public: false, like_facebook: nil, share_facebook: false, follow_twitter: nil, share_t
witter: false, follow_instagram: nil, shazam_track: nil, about_track: "", lyrics: "", credits: "", price: #<BigDecimal:7fa4767

d2f18,'0.0',9(18)>, name_your_price: false>, @mounted_as=:file, @cache_id="1461881968-11098-8389", @filename="Not_Alone_Lyrics
_-_RED_-_Until_We_Have_Faces.mp3", @original_filename="Not_Alone_Lyrics_-_RED_-_Until_We_Have_Faces.mp3", @file=#<CarrierWave:
:SanitizedFile:0x007fa46d079658 @file="/Users/*****/Desktop/projects/*****/public/uploads/tmp/1461881968-11098-8389/Not_
Alone_Lyrics_-_RED_-_Until_We_Have_Faces.mp3", @original_filename=nil, @content_type="audio/mp3">, @versions={}>
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 643ms (ActiveRecord: 496.1ms)
```

How can I access the string:

```
/Users/*****/Desktop/projects/*****/public/uploads/tmp/1461881968-11098-8389/Not_
Alone_Lyrics_-_RED_-_Until_We_Have_Faces.mp3
```

Comment: so do you need a long path to a temp file?

Comment: that is correct yes.

Comment: I dont exactly remember: open `pry` and try: `@track.file.path`, `@track.file.filepath`, also you can look to methods of cw as: `@track.file.methods`

Comment: thanks will try that! the workaround i found is like this  `audio = @track.file`, then again `audio = audio.file` and then to access what i want is again `audio.file` . it works this way but its awkard

Comment: @theTinMan I am sorry but they are two related but not closely related questions. In one question i ask how to get duration of song, here i ask how to get to the path of the song, totally different questions.

Comment: The answer to this question will answer the other.

Comment: Eventually yes but doesn't mean my way is the correct way of doing things, i do not see whats wrong with my other question being there, if not for me, it might help someone else in the future.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11917027/128421

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the standard Tempfile object, you can simply call `#path`

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html#method-i-path

Comment: that isn't allow access to internally stored path to  file