# Error when trying to host a file with amazon s3 and carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, carrierwave

For unknow reason I'm getting an error when trying to host a file on my web app.

I have the model **Attachment** that corresponds to either an image or another type of file, which I determine using the `origin` field. An **Attachment** belongs to an **Item** and I upload a file via the **AttachmentUploader**.

An **User** can choose to host either an image or a file. There are therefore two different buttons available with either the `image` or `file` parameter defined according to the button the **User** click on.

Then, I do a validation on the `origin` field to verify that the file that the user is trying to upload is indeed consistent with the file that we want to host.

In local storage I have no problem and the file is hosted correctly. However, on my production application hosted on heroku, I am storing my files via carrierwave and amazon s3, and this bug has occurred.

According to the logs, I get the error `TypeError (no implicit conversion of Aws::S3::Object into String)` when I try to open the file so that I can check the content type.

```
2020-09-30T20:43:03.185219+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-09-30T20:43:03.185125 #4]  INFO -- : [9fb8796c-5513-4881-ba8c-77a871db3e08] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 184ms (ActiveRecord: 2.4ms | Allocations: 4583)

2020-09-30T20:43:03.185964+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-09-30T20:43:03.185892 #4] FATAL -- : [9fb8796c-5513-4881-ba8c-77a871db3e08]

2020-09-30T20:43:03.185965+00:00 app[web.1]: [9fb8796c-5513-4881-ba8c-77a871db3e08] TypeError (no implicit conversion of Aws::S3::Object into String):

2020-09-30T20:43:03.185966+00:00 app[web.1]: [9fb8796c-5513-4881-ba8c-77a871db3e08]

2020-09-30T20:43:03.185966+00:00 app[web.1]: [9fb8796c-5513-4881-ba8c-77a871db3e08] app/models/attachment.rb:36:in `initialize'

2020-09-30T20:43:03.185967+00:00 app[web.1]: [9fb8796c-5513-4881-ba8c-77a871db3e08] app/models/attachment.rb:36:in `open'

2020-09-30T20:43:03.185967+00:00 app[web.1]: [9fb8796c-5513-4881-ba8c-77a871db3e08] app/models/attachment.rb:36:in `check_content_type_origin'

2020-09-30T20:43:03.185967+00:00 app[web.1]: [9fb8796c-5513-4881-ba8c-77a871db3e08] app/controllers/attachments_controller.rb:55:in `create'
```

**Attachment** - *app/models/attachment.rb*

```rb
# @author despla_g
class Attachment < ApplicationRecord

  # An Attachment belongs to an Item
  belongs_to :item

  # An Attachment belongs to an User
  belongs_to :user

  # An Attachment can be an Image or a File
  enum origin: [:image, :file]

  # Fields attachment and origin must be filled
  validates_presence_of :attachment, :origin

  # Check attachment content type according to origin
  validate :check_content_type_origin, if: -> { attachment.present? }

  # An Attachment is hosted via carrierwave
  mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader

  # Check the content type of the attachment
  # According to the origin value
  def check_content_type_origin
    if origin == "image"
      errors.add(:attachment, "must be an image") if !MimeMagic.by_magic(File.open(attachment.file.file)).type.include?("image")
    elsif origin == "file"

      ##ERROR ON THE LINE BELOW
      errors.add(:attachment, "can't be an image") if MimeMagic.by_magic(File.open(attachment.file.file)).type.include?("image")



    end
  end

end
```

**AttachmentUploader** - *app/uploaders/attachment_uploader.rb*

```rb
# This file is the attachment uploader and allows to store all items file
class AttachmentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Allows to include MiniMagick
  # In order to use the resize_to_fill process
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Allows to define the store_dir path
  # In order to store attachments at this path
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.item.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.origin}/#{model.item.id}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Allows to create a specific version of the item image
  # In order to display the item image in the items card
  version :card, if: :is_image? do
    process resize_to_fill: [500, 250]
  end

  # Allows to create a specific version of the item image
  # In order to display the item image in the items list
  version :list, if: :is_image? do
    process resize_to_fill: [50, 50]
  end

  # Allows to check if the uploaded file is an image
  # In order to create specifics versions only for image file
  def is_image?(file = nil)
    file.content_type.to_s.include?("image") ? true : false
  end

end
```

**CarrierWave** - *config/initializers/carrierwave.rb*

```rb
CarrierWave.configure do |config|

  # Use local storage if in development or test
  if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?
    config.storage = :file
  end

  # Use AWS storage if in production
  if Rails.env.production?
    if ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'].present? && ENV['AWS_SECRET_KEY'].present? && ENV['AWS_BUCKET_NAME'].present? && ENV['AWS_REGION'].present?
      config.storage = :aws
      config.aws_bucket = ENV['AWS_BUCKET_NAME']
      config.aws_credentials = {
        access_key_id:  ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'],                    # required
        secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_KEY'],                 # required
        region: ENV['AWS_REGION']                                 # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
      }

      # The maximum period for authenticated_urls is only 7 days.
       config.aws_authenticated_url_expiration = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7

       config.aws_attributes = -> { {
         expires: 1.week.from_now.httpdate,
         cache_control: 'max-age=604800'
       } }
    else
      config.storage = :file
    end
  end

  config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"                   # to let carrierWave work on heroku
end
```

#### Project Infos

**Ruby version** : *2.7.1*
**Rails version** : *6.0.3.2*
**Database engine** : *PostgreSQL*

Thanks to reading me.

Comment: @dbugger Error 500, and I put the server logs in my post

Comment: Oh, sorry! Its this line :
`errors.add(:attachment, "can't be an image") if MimeMagic.by_magic(File.open(attachment.file.file)).type.include?("image")`, In the model Attachment (attachment is also the field where the image is stored)

Comment: Did you try `MimeMagic.by_magic(attachment.file)`? Using `File.open` is most likely superfluous as you already have an IO object. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917027/how-to-get-the-real-file-from-s3-using-carrierwave

Comment: Yes i tried, but I get `wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)`